# EntityListener preflush: replace an entity with another

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com

With Api-platform, I'm trying to create an address entity, that will be linked to other entities.

I'd like to use the Doctrine EntityListener to watch every Address creation/update (even when it's part of another entity creation/update), and if an Address already exists with the new values, return this one instead of creating a new one or updating the other one.

I tried to replace the id of the new address by the existing one, but then Doctrine tries to insert the new address with this id, or update the previous address id by the new one, creating this kind of errors:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE address SET id = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [1, 2]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"address_pkey\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.",

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO address (id,other fields) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [1, 'other stuff']:\n\nSQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"address_pkey\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.",
```

I tried different things with the entityManager and the unitOfWork, but didn't manage to replace the address with the correct one yet.

The main objectives are :

- that it is transparent for the user of the endpoint (they don't need to know if the address is new or existing)
- that any dev that'd make a new entity linked to address wouldn't have to do anything special to keep the address unicity. It should work by just linking the entities together.

Thank you for any help.